# How can I check time taken while creating a million ndarrays?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm trying to figure out how long will it take to create a million of `ndarray` (numpy array) and compare it to the time taken by `list` with the `timeit` library but I'm getting the following syntax error:

```py
File "<timeit-src>", line 2
    [1 2 3 4 5]
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And this error makes sense but I don't even know how can I do this.

The following is code I tried so far

```py
import numpy as np
import timeit

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ndarr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

list_time = timeit.timeit(stmt=f'{arr}', number=1000000)
ndarray_time = timeit.timeit(stmt=f'{ndarr}', number=1000000)

print('list takes', list_time, sep=': ')
print('ndarray takes', ndarray_time, sep=': ')
```

on `list` result is as an expected one but on `ndarray` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a callable:

```py
list_time = timeit.timeit(stmt=lambda: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], number=1000000)
ndarray_time = timeit.timeit(stmt=lambda: np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), number=1000000)
#lambda: (ndarr := np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) - (if actual assignment matters...?)
```

You can also pass a string, but as a comment has alluded to here, you'll need to set it up properly:

```py
list_time = timeit.timeit(stmt="a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]", number=1000000)
ndarray_time = timeit.timeit(stmt=lambda: "a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])", setup="import numpy as np", number=1000000)
```

Comment: how `ndarray` is slower than `list`

Comment: @Gad why, did you think it's faster?

Comment: @Gad I'm not sure where you've read that... instantiating the object is probably slower because the interpreter has to look up the method, whereas a literal array string is almost instantaneous because it lacks that part. Actual operations are faster in numpy because it uses C for its loops, which can be several magnitudes faster than the equivalent in python

Comment: @Gad It can't possibly be faster. Both expressions create the same list, and then the numpy expression **additionally** turns that list into an array.

Comment: Just check [Array is faster and that is because ArrayList uses a fixed amount of array](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/394625/Which-is-better-array-ArrayList-or-List-in-terms-o) and [As the array size increase, Numpy gets around 30 times faster than Python List.](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-fast-numpy-really-is-e9111df44347)

Comment: @Gad the example doesn't time the actual **instantiation** of the array, just operations on top of it

Comment: `np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` first makes the list, and then passes it to the `np.array` function.  Yes, creating a `ndarray` is not time-free.  It's the use of the array, once created, that can be fast, provided you use the compiled methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [628]: arr=[1,2,3,4,5]                                                                            
In [629]: ndarr=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])                                                                
In [630]: f'{arr}'                                                                                   
Out[630]: '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
In [631]: f'{ndarr}'                                                                                 
Out[631]: '[1 2 3 4 5]'
```

The problem is that while `"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"` is an executable expression, `"[1 2 3 4 5]"` is not.  It's hard to create an executable expression from an existing `ndarray` - not impossible, but you have to work at it.

In an `ipython` session, it's simple to run such timeit tests:

```
In [632]: timeit [1,2,4,5]                                                                           
60.6 ns ± 1.77 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
In [633]: timeit np.array([1,2,4,5])                                                                 
2.22 µs ± 20.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The `repr` is better, looking more list-like

```
In [635]: f'{repr(ndarr)}'                                                                           
Out[635]: 'array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])'
```

but even that needs tweaking to get the `array` part right.